# Linear Tranformation - derivates

Tags: linear-algebra

$\delta : C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow  C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$
$\delta (f)= f'$ is a l.t. So I want the Kernel and the image. 
well,  I know if $f' = 0$ then $f = a$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$. So $ker(\delta)=$ {$f$ is constant}. well, $im(\delta)=$ {$f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$/f has primitive}. Can I express the im set in other way. and What about function that has no primitive? some explanations.

Comment: Is $C^{\infty}{\mathbb{R}}$ the set of all infinitly differentiable functions?

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that a continuous function always has a primitive. Thus $\text{im}(\delta)=C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$!

Comment: So have I got a isomorphism?...

Comment: @Elll: no, because it's not bijective

Answer (score 1):

Every $f\in C^{\infty}$ has a primitive :

$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$$

Your $\delta$ is surjective

Comment: that if consider $\int_a^x f(x) dx$ as a function?. Ok. thank

Comment: @Elll : Sorry, I meant $\int_0^x f(t) dt $ or else it didn't make any sense ;)